# Creating a Batch File VS x64 Command Prompt

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, command-line, terminal

I would like to create a batch file to  do some instructions in the x64 command prompt of VS13. The instructions are the next ones:

```
cd C:\SomeDirectory
checkAPIenv AnotherDirectory
cd AnotherDirectory
devenv Projectname.sln
```

I have created a batch file with them but when I load it in the console, it only does up to checkAPIenv, then does nothing.

Comment: I forgot to say that checkAPIenv is a .cmd file with more instructions. That, on the other hand, is not mine.

Comment: You must add CALL command before executing a bat/cmd file from another one: `call checkAPIenv AnotherDirectory`

Comment: Thanks!! And, is there any way to open the script directly in the VS command prompt?